# windows server 2008 r2 - can't get apache to run on port 80

Tags: windows, apache

I have a rackspace cloud server running windows server 2008 r2. I've uninstalled IIS because I want to install Apache.

I've installed Apache but it fails everytime i try to run it when i listen to port 80.

I've run the command netstat -aon|finderstr "80" and i see the following:

C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -aon|findstr "80"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    10.180.15.249:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  UDP    10.180.15.249:137      *:*                                    4
  UDP    10.180.15.249:138      *:*                                    4

So what are these things running on port 80 and why can't i get apache to start?  Is there an alternative port for to run apache under that will work just as well as 80?

Comment: Just in case others are having this same problem, the solution I found was uninstall IIS (or maybe just disable it) and then disable all MSSQL services. Next go to control panel and edit your firewall. Click Allow a program through Windows Firewall. Click Add Port. Type HTTP and port number 80, choose TCP, click OK.  This opens port 80.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To enable port 80 on **Windows Server 2008 R2**:

NOTE: This assumes that **IIS is not installed**. I added this firewall rule to enable **Apache** to accept connections on port 80.

1. Click Start->Control Panel->Windows Firewall
2. Click "Advanced Settings" in the left panel of Windows Firewall
3. Click "Inbound rules" in the left panel of Advanced Settings
4. Click "New Rule..." in right "Actions" panel
5. Select "Port" and click "Next>"
6. Select "TCP", then "Specific local ports:" (should already be selected)
7. Type 80 in the box (just the number) and click "Next>"
8. Select "Allow the connection" and click "Next>"
9. Leave all profiles checked  and click "Next>"
10. Enter a name and click "Finish".

Your server should now be able to accept connections on port 80.

Comment: Isn't that functionally the same solution Robbiegod posted as a comment to his own question a few weeks ago?

Comment: I know i answered this myself in the comments, but because you gave more detail I'll give you the win!  Thanks for the assist regardless.  I no longer have this server running anymore so i can't verify anyone elses answers.

Answer (score 3):

On a Windows server running MSSQL, disabling MSSQL ReportServer (display name: SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)) services and World Wide Web Publishing services, resolved the problem for me.  No need to fiddle with firewall settings or changing default port configurations.

Answer (score 2):

I am running a windows 2008 r2 with IIS and sql server.  I added an additional IP address to run apache and configured IIS to bind to one of the IP addresses.  I ran into the same problem and found suggestions about disabling SQL reporting services and WinRM.  These solutions did not work for me.

There are many different services that can use the http server api(http.sys) and will then show up simply as pid 4.

I found the answer at the link below.  The essence of the link is to go to a command prompt.
Type netsh press enter.
Type http and press enter.
add iplisten ipaddress=x.x.x.x

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc307219(v=vs.85).aspx

There is also a method to disable http.sys in the registry but I do not know what the ramifications of that might be.

I hope this helps someone else so they don't waste as much time as I did trying to find the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I find that I can successfully add the firewall rules to make my own server run on port 80 within the vshost visual studio debug environment but when running as a service it only works on local host from the machine and not from external hosts.

Very frustrating. Seems that there are possible conditions in the firewall which are not exposed in the Windows Firewall configuration interface very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

With IIS installed you need to change bindings on web sites in IIS so that none uses "all available addresses":80 binding. Either change the ports, or change listening IP addresses.